# How to launch a modal from a url change with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a working "launch modal from an event" using the ApplicationRoute but I'd like to track the modal changes in the url if possible.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    modal: function() {
      view = Ember.View.create({
        templateName: "modal",
        controller: this.controller,
        content: []
      }).appendTo('body');
    }
  }
});
```

If I change the url, how can I trigger a modal to show w/ a given context (using the url params to build it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how centralized you want this behavior to be, you could add a path observer to the application controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  //...
  currentPathDidChange: function () {
    switch(this.get('currentPath')){
      case 'foo-route.index':
        //trigger modal change
        break;
    }
  }.observes('currentPath')
  //...
});
```

Comment: This can be in a single location. So with your example I could wire it up on the ApplicationController ? Or the ApplicationRoute ?

Comment: @ToranBillups Just edited my answer. It can be done from the ApplicationController.